# Formatting Issues in MS Access Report - The Height property does not change with the CanShink and CanGrow property

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In an MS Access Report, I have text-boxes with the CanShrink and CanGrow property set to true. A procedure runs when the form is opened, dynamically adding data to these text boxes. I retrieve the Height property from these text-boxes after data is added but it appears that it is retrieving the original height of the text-box (the height that it was created as in design view).

Is there any way around this? I am essentially trying to create a table like structure, where the height of the and number of cells are unknown until run-time. Should tables really be so difficult to make?

Here is a visual of my problem:

[image]

Note:

Form msdn: "When a control shrinks, the controls below it move up the page." That hasn't been the case in my  project, though when a control grows, the controls below it move down. The main problem is that bottom border of the adjacent cell does not line up when a cell grows.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Indigo, I don't think so. I probably just took a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the Left boxes are preventing the Right boxes from moving up.

Comment: I don't want the right boxes to move up. I want the left box height to adjust in order to match the height of the right box.